# Naming convention (or a term) for parameters that could represent either a collection or a single item

Tags: language-agnostic, naming-conventions

My particular case deals with Ruby, though it could apply to almost any language.

I've been using `noun_or_nouns` to name parameters that could represent either a collection or a single item. For example: `action_or_actions`, `favorite_sidewalk_or_sidewalks`

Is there a less awkward naming convention? Is there a single word to describe objects that could be a collection or a single item?  I've mainly  dealt with C++ and C#, and this sort of thing rarely comes up in either of those languages.

I'm looking for something self-documenting, so that callers of the method know that either a collection or a single item are acceptable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would just use the plural name and drop the singular. Is there ever a time you would treat it any differently, even if there's only one item?

```
names.each do |name|
    #do something with the name
end
```

Comment: I'm preferably looking for something self-documenting, so that callers of the method know that either a collection or a single item are acceptable. However, I did ask about *conventions*, so this might be the convention...

Comment: When coming up with a name is awkward, it's often a sign that my design is a bit awkward. Personally, I wouldn't make it an explicit option. If you want to offer an option for convenience, you could have two different methods (and call the singular-param method from the one that accepts a collection), but that seems a bit contrived to me. As appealing as flexibility is, [it’s a double-edged sword](http://www.threeriversinstitute.org/AbstractVsConcreteParameters.html) (though article is perhaps not as relevant for dynamic languages). Perhaps a more experienced Rubyist could weigh in...

Comment: I don't think that this is at all awkward -- it's actually a common "idiom" in Ruby libraries to allow both a collection and single item for certain parameters, All it takes is `Array(my_parameter).each` to deal with the parameter is though it were a collection. I haven't seen a single naming convention, though. If it's most common to simply give such parameters a plural name, then you've answered the question.